# Primefaces dialog hide method breaks my css

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to let an user accept a bid chosen from a datatable, but when I choose to cancel the dialog, my css breaks.

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" header="Bid" widgetVar="bidDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                <p:outputPanel id="bidDetail" style="text-align:center;">                       
                    <p:outputLabel value="You want to accept this bid?" />
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" value="Yes" action="#{bidsBean.acceptBid()}"/>
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" value="No" onclick="dlg.hide()"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
```

Backing bean:

```
public String acceptBid() {
    repairService.acceptBid(selectedBid);
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Bid successfully accepted!")); 
    repairBean.setSelectedRepair(null);
    return "repairs.xhtml";       
}
```

Css:

```
body {
font-size: 11pt;
```

}

```
.narrow {
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%;
```

}

The narrow styleclass dissapears after hiding the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of primefaces?

if is the version 5.0 
try with :

```
<p:confirmDialog header="Bid" severity="alert" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" global="true">
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" actionListener="#{bidsBean.acceptBid}" oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide()" icon="ui-icon-check" ajax="true"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="PF('dlg').hide();" type="button" icon="ui-icon-close"/></p:confirmDialog>
```